# Как сделать перенос текста в listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как сделать перенос текста в listbox?

```
<ListBox x:Name="resolved" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
         AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="394" Margin="748,96,0,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="InWork_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
         FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="16">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="Gainsboro"/>
            <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Padding" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Перенос какого текста и куда? Опишите подробнее, можно с эскизом того что есть и то что хотите получить

Comment: Нужно чтобы поля в Listbox'e переносились на следующую строчку без textblock'a

Comment: Без какого textblock'a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придется переопределить шаблон элемента списка и указать ему необходимость переноса текста явно. К тому же придется отключить горизонтальный скроллбар, иначе контейнер будет всегда давать элементам столько места сколько они хотят:

```
<ListBox FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="16"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]